# Setting up callback urls to receive information

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to figure out how to setup a callback url to receive payment status information from a payment gateway.

Here's a summary of the whole setup. There is a backend (API endpoints)built with Laravel 5.8 that will be consumed by a react app and a mobile app. Both apps will be using the payment gateway's web and mobile sdks to initiate payment transactions.

Then the payment gateway should respond with a payment status by calling the callback api I need to set up.

This is my first attempt at doing something like this so pardon me if I am way off but here's what I have written

Callback endpoint

```
Route::post('order/payment/status', 'PaymentController@getStatus'); // receives payment status
```

PaymentController `getstatus()` method

```
public function getStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $paymentMethod          = $request->paymentMethod;
        $amount                 = $request->amount;
        $providerCode           = $request->provider;
        $customerName           = $request->customerName;
        $customerEmail          = $request->customerEmail;
        $paymentDescription     = $request->paymentDescription;
        $paymentStatus          = $request->paaymentStatus;
        $transactionReference   = $request->transactionReference;

        // update my record based on the paymentStatus
    }
```

Is this the proper way to do it? I feel like it should be a `get` request and not a `post`. Please help.

Comment: It will have to be whichever HTTP method the payment gateway specifies. Absolutely, nothing wrong with what you've done though. If it is anything other than a `GET` request, make sure to add the uri to your `$except` array in your `csrf` middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: @Rwd thanks, I will do just that.

Comment: @Rwd the uri to be added to the `csrf` middleware will be that of the payment gateway, right?

Comment: `order/payment/status`. The route for the callback.

Comment: @Rwd Alright then. I will test with the payment gateway support team.

Answer (score 5):

### You're in the right path.

I'll leave you with some tips and advises that I wish I knew back then.

1) Define your **route** outside of your `auth` middleware group and disable CSRF protection for its url, that can be achieved in the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

2) `get, post or any`: `post` is the recommended. But, perhaps that's not something you can choose. The far majority of gateways will send your backend a post request, however, once I've worked with a gateway that sent get requests, if that's your case, define an `any` route.

3) Get, post or any, **ALWAYS** validate the signature of the received request with the payment gateway. That's a safety must that will discard requests not sent from the payment gateway. Every payment gateway has got to have this, find it in the documentation.

4) Log every request payload (`$request->all()`) to file or database before anything in your controller, or if you prefer, integrate your system with an error tracking service like Sentry, for example (that's the neat way). That will save you a lot of trouble in case an error stops script execution.

5) The easiest way to speed up the development process is **to test your code locally** (without the need to go through checkout every time), to do so, get a hold of the request payload from the payment gateway (json, probably), save on Postman and use it to send your local backend posts, simulating the request from the payment gateway (bypass signature validation when testing, of course).

6) Don't fit the payment gateway molds, but make them fit yours instead. Meaning: don't go saving a raw **meaningful** data in your database without transforming it into a pattern that your logic recognizes. That's a **best practice** that will avoid you headaches in the future (in case you need to change payment gateway).

Dirty pratical example for comprehension:

```php
switch ($request->paymentStatus) {
    case 'SUCCESS':
        $status = 'success';
        break;

    case 'CANCELLED_BY_USER':
    case 'CANCELLED_BY_ANTIFRAUD':
        $status = 'canceled';
        break;

    default:
        $status = 'unknown';
        break;
}
```

7) Continuing on about the **best practice** mentioned above, if you ever need to code checkout in PHP, consider using a known payment processing library like [Omnipay](https://omnipay.thephpleague.com/), for example. It's a whole new learning, but, that learning will be enough for life.

8) Log every user action taken in your Admin (a charge button, a status creation button, a notification send button, everything...). You never know when you're gonna get that call.

That's it. Hope it helps